# rank of a rectangular Vandermonde matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank, geometric-progressions

Let the $m\times (n+1)$ rectangular Vandermonde matrix be $V$. More specifically, the matrix $V$ has the following form.

$V=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_1 & \cdots & a_1^{n} \\ 
1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_2^{n}\\ 
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots  &\vdots \\ 
1 & a_m & \cdots & a_m^{n} 
\end{pmatrix}$
, where $m \geq n$.

I want a proof that $ \operatorname{rank}(V)=n$, if and only if the $a_i$ take exactly $n$ different values. Can you recommend me any paper or book that has a formal proof?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but the matrix that I'm concerned about is $m\times (n+1)$, not $m\times n$. The last term is $a_i^n$, and I want a conclusion that $rank(V)=n$.

Comment: I re-edited the question. Please let me know if my re-edition is wrong.

Comment: I doubt that this is what you want. Can you clarify what "$n$ of $a_i$ distinct" means precisely for you?

Comment: Alternatively, you could write down the interpretation of your question fir $n=1$.

Comment: Sure. There are $n+1$ columns in $V$, including ones in the first column too. And there are $m$ elements of $a_i$, $a_1, a_2, \cdots a_m$. What I meant by "$n$ of $a_i$ distinct" is that the number of different element of $a_i$, $i=1,2,...,m$ are $n$.

Comment: Ok, I have edited the phrase to reflect this intended meaning. The previous formulation meant "at least n different".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will prove:  If there are at least $k$ distinct values of the $a_i$ the rank is at least $k$.

Applying this for $k=n$ and $k=n+1$ gives the desired characterization of rank $n$.

Proof of the claim:

If there are less than $k$ distinct values there are less than $k$ distinct rows and the rank is clearly less than $k$.

If there are at least $k$ distinct values we can take the submatrix consisting of $k$ rows corresponding to distinct values and the first $k$ columns.

Its determinant is
$$\prod_{1\le r < s \le k}(a_{i_r}-a_{i_s}) $$
which is nonzero so the rank is at least $k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question: If $V$ is a rectangular matrix, then the determinant can be defined?

Comment: No. It cannot be defined.

Comment: I have another question: The maximum rank that $V$ can take is $n+1$ if $(n+1)\leq m$. In this case, how can you still reach the conclusion that the rank is $n$?

Comment: @user568810 In case you have not noticed: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still couldn't understand the logic. Can you give me a link of a website, paper or book that deals with this problem? In a nutshell, I want to know if $m \times n$ Vandermonde matrix has rank $d$, if and only if $d$ of the elements take different values.

Comment: Well, that is what I prove here so you might just say what part you do not understand.

Comment: "If there are less than k distinct values there are less than k distinct rows and the rank is clearly less than k." I don't follow why the rank is clearly less than $k$. To show that, we need to show other rows are linearly dependent of the $k$ rows? I don't know why the rank is clearly less than $k$.

Comment: @user568810 Being *identical* is the strongest form of linear independence there is. You can eliminate all identical rows except one by forming the difference to an identical row, so the rank is clearly *at most* the number of distinct values of $a_i$.